# Best way to wait until prices load completely (such as on comparision websites)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I tried using implicit wait but it did not work somehow and then I also tried explicit wait such as `sleep` but again it did not work and also not a good practice.
I then looked at fluent wait but because I am using the `PageFactory` and old version of fluent wait is deprecated, does anyone know how can I implement fluent wait along with `PageFactory`.

Comment: Could you please include some code with your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go...

```
    public static void waitForElement(WebElement element){
    try {
        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                .withTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(60000))
                .pollingEvery(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
                .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
        waiting(100);
        //can add further action here
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```